# Defining an Em Dash with Length Greater Than the Cabin Default

Tags: fonts, punctuation, font-encodings, lengths, definition

I have noticed that the length of an em dash is not always uniform, depending upon the font being used.

Consider the following code which defines an em dash:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\textit{Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.} 

\hfill \emdash Yogi Berra
\end{document}
```

and which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the above code so that I can increase the length of the em dash produced by `\emdash`? Naively, I thought, perhaps that adding another dash would accomplish this, but it doesn't.

Thank you.

Comment: You could just use a rule: `\newcommand{\emdash}{\rule[4.7pt]{20pt}{1.3pt}}` (first number is height off baseline, second number is width, third is thickness)

Comment: I guess you could also use two en dashes `\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak{--}\nobreak{--}\nobreak\hskip0pt}` but maybe that's too wide?

Comment: @frabjous Thank you for your comments; the first works exceptionally well for me because the width is adjustable---and as such---contains no seam, as can occur when one tries to "sew" two em dashes together. Please consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, one possibility would be to use a rule. You could define a custom `\emdash` command like this:

```
\newcommand{\emdash}{\rule[4.7pt]{20pt}{1.3pt}}
```

One advantage of this approach is you have complete fine-grained control over the length and other dimensions. In the above, the first (optional) argument, `4.7pt`, is how far above the baseline to raise the rule, the second argument, `20pt`, is the width of the rule, and the last argument, here `1.3pt` is the thickness (or "height") of the rule.

Tweak as you see fit.

One disadvantage is that you're not using a text character from a font at all, so if someone copies and pastes from your PDF, they won't get anything representing the "dash".

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\newcommand{\emdash}{\rule[4.7pt]{20pt}{1.3pt}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\textit{Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.} 

\hfill \emdash Yogi Berra
\end{document}
```

[image: emdash with rule]

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a font that's compatible with Cabin as far as stroke thickness is concerned, having a properly sized em dash; `cmss` seems fit.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}

\newcommand{\funnyquote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent\textit{#1}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash#2%
}

\begin{document}

\funnyquote{Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.}{Yogi Berra}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Unicode Character DOUBLE EM-DASH (U+2E3A) but Cabin doesn't have this glyph. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use two regular em-dashes, but add some negative kerning so there is no visible gap, like so: `---\!---`

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak ---\!--- \nobreak\hskip0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\textit{Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.} 

\hfill \emdash Yogi Berra
\end{document}
```

If that's too much, you can also use two or three en-dashes, or increase the kerning: `\kern -5pt` (instead of just `\!`) or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; however, I had a little trouble running your code---until I replaced `\!` with $\!$. I also noticed, when I ran the revised code, that a tiny "seam" appears in the output (hardly noticeable, but it's there). This, I was able to get around by then replacing $\!$ with `\kern` and by, trial and error, replacing -5pt by values of smaller magnitude until, by inspection, the tiny seam disappeared.

Comment: be aware that if you try to fake a glyph copy&paste can fail. Consider to add an /ActualText (e.g. with the accsupp package).

Comment: @mlchristians You're using TeX Live prior to 2020. I believe it's time to update.